# Android Two Libraries with Sync Adapters only one called

Tags: android, android-library, android-syncadapter

I'm really puzzled with this one. I think the issue stems from the library applications manifests merging.

I have two sync adapters, from two different libraries. I keep playing with the code, I essentially can get either the first or second sync adapter to work.

Case one, all template files are named the same, libOne's sync adapter is launched. I rename the XML file referenced in  android:resource="@xml/filenamehere" for BOTH files
to be unique and not the default. Result, libTwo's sync is activated? That's odd.

My solution is to make a third sync adapter in the actual application and handle both of these adapters in one file, but I hate not understanding why something happened. Note I changed the package names to libOne libTwo.

These libraries are from the same university, part of the same project by the same author. The only difference is the path names, adapters name, the authority and account type. Thus they are literal copy and paste mirror images. I have tried making all these items the same, no change. Only thing thats made a difference that I cant seem to control is renaming the files. Also tried changing the allow parallel flag. I'm guessing the OS doesn't like the launching of my dual adapters.

I am looking at the logcat, but mostly I have an notification I create as services are annoying to get to appear in the logcat as they are of a different thread than the app.

How I launch the services

```
if(!isMyServiceRunning(libOne.data_sync.SyncService.class, context)){
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Starting service confirmTrips....");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, libOne.SyncService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    if(!isMyServiceRunning(libTwo.smap.SyncService.class, context)){
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Starting service sendTripData....");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, libTwo.smap.SyncService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }


    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(mAccount, LIBTWO_AUTHORITY, 1);
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, LIBTWO_AUTHORITY, true);
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(mAccount, LIBTWO_AUTHORITY, new Bundle(), SYNC_INTERVAL);
    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(mAccount, LIBONE_AUTHORITY, 1);
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, LIBONE_AUTHORITY, true);
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(mAccount, LIBONE_AUTHORITY, new Bundle(), SYNC_INTERVAL);
```

Files for the service

```
   <service
            android:name="libone.data_sync.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/libOnesyncadapter" />
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="libone.data_sync.StubContentProvider"
            android:authorities="libone.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:syncable="true" />
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:accountType="accounttypeone.org"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 // adapter
<sync-adapter
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:contentAuthority="libone.provider"
        android:accountType="liboneaccounttype"
        android:userVisible="false"
        android:supportsUploading="true"
        android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
        android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>

 ////LIBTwo

        <service
                android:name="libtwo.smap.SyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/libTwosyncadapter" />
        </service>
        <provider
            android:name="libtwo.smap.StubContentProvider"
            android:authorities="libtwo.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:syncable="true"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:accountType="accounttypetwo.org"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:contentAuthority="libtwo.provider"
        android:accountType="libtwo.org"
        android:userVisible="false"
        android:supportsUploading="true"
        android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
        android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

Logcat

```
08-16 14:37:48.458     1535-956/? D/[WINGTIP_NOTI]ParseAlgorithm﹕ piece=Syncing libTwoAdapter  Aug 16, 2015 2:37:48 PM id:16908415 name:text
08-16 14:37:48.458     1535-956/? D/[WINGTIP_NOTI]ParseAlgorithm﹕ body is : Syncing libTwoAdapter  Aug 16, 2015 2:37:48 PM
08-16 14:37:48.458     1535-956/? D/[WINGTIP_NOTI]ParseAlgorithm﹕ line 2 = Syncing libTwoAdapter CFC  Aug 16, 2015 2:37:48 PM
08-16 14:37:48.458     1535-956/? D/[WINGTIP_NOTI]WingtipNotificationListenerService﹕ line 1 = Study, line2 = Syncing libTwoAdapter  Aug 16, 2015 2:37:48 PM
08-16 14:37:48.488    1535-1535/? I/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ NOTIFICAITON onReceived
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? I/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ ServicePackages.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? I/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ index : 10202 packageName : time : 1439757468418 title : Study textMessage : Syncing libTwoAdapter  Aug 16, 2015 2:37:48 PM
    addressText :  isVibrate : false
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ transfer()
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ =================================================================
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ Message ID :             10202
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ Package Name :           
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ Sender :                 Study
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ Address :
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ Title :
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ Body :                   Syncing libTwoAdapter  Aug 16, 2015 2:37:48 PM
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ Message Time :           1439757468418
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ isVibrate :              false
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ =================================================================
08-16 14:37:48.498    1535-1535/? V/[WINGTIP_NOTI]NotificationAdapter﹕ Disable Notification generalNotification packageNamae :
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the accountType. In making the third service, I could not get it to run till I had it match my libraries accountType.

Answer (score 0):

I had the accountType set as X for the first Library and for the second accountType Y. This matches the nightmare I've had with getting a security exception when trying to get or create explicitly an account. I could only generate accounts from one of the libraries, the error would say I was calling with a missmatched ID.

My bigger issue, I didn't change the account type in one of the fields when I tried to make it all uniform.